# Duplicate keys in JSON, how to consider only one key

Tags: json, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

While loading file from hive, I am getting an exception:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Duplicate column(s) : "department_name" found, cannot save to JSON format;

The code is:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('pyspark')
sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
result = sqlContext.read.json("path/department_dup_key.json")
result.registerTempTable("djson")
result_set=sqlContext.sql("select * from djson").collect()
```

File content of "department_dup_key.json" is:

```
{"department_id":7,"department_name":"golf"}
{"department_id":8,"department_name":"apparel"}
{"department_id":9,"department_name":"fitness"}
{"department_id":10,"department_name":"testing","department_name":"Hellloooo"}
```

Can I ignore the second "department_name" when reading the dataframe?

Comment: is there some logic behind the selection? like first or last or something ?

Comment: required all values, by considering only one duplicate key and ignoring remains

Comment: so, for `{"department_id":10,"department_name":"testing","department_name":"Hellloooo"}` it be saved as `{"department_id":10,"department_name":"testing"}`

Comment: Yes, that's what i need